# Transfer multiple columns string values to numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working at a data frame like this:

```
   id type1 type2 type3
0   1   dog   NaN   NaN
1   2   cat   NaN   NaN
2   3   dog   cat   NaN
3   4   cow   NaN   NaN
4   5   dog   NaN   NaN
5   6   cat   NaN   NaN
6   7   cat   dog   cow
7   8   dog   NaN   NaN
```

How can I transfer it to the following dataframe? Thank you.

```
   id  dog  cat  cow
0   1  1.0  NaN  NaN
1   2  NaN  1.0  NaN
2   3  1.0  1.0  NaN
3   4  NaN  NaN  1.0
4   5  1.0  NaN  NaN
5   6  NaN  1.0  NaN
6   7  1.0  1.0  1.0
7   8  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried using `OneHotEncoder` from `sklearn`?

Comment: Not yet, this's not for machine learning, so I'm not if it's a appropriate way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First filter ony `type` columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), so possible call [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html). Then for `0/1` output use `max` by first level of `MultiIndex` and change `1` to `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html). Last add first column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(like='type').stack().str.get_dummies().max(level=0).mask(lambda x: x == 0)
```

Or use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and `max` per columns names and last change `1` to `NaN`s:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.filter(like='type'), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .max(level=0, axis=1)
         .mask(lambda x: x == 0))
```

---

```
df = df[['id']].join(df1)
print (df)
   id  cat  cow  dog
0   1  NaN  NaN  1.0
1   2  1.0  NaN  NaN
2   3  1.0  NaN  1.0
3   4  NaN  1.0  NaN
4   5  NaN  NaN  1.0
5   6  1.0  NaN  NaN
6   7  1.0  1.0  1.0
7   8  NaN  NaN  1.0
```